# see where using statement is coming from

Tags: c#

I'm going through someone else's code where they have a `using OpenDataAnswer.DataSchemas;` statement. I have a working version of their code but need to copy a file to another project and I cannot figure out how to resolve this using statement. I cannot find a dll reference of the same name and a search of the entire solution does not show another namespace by that name. Is there any way I can see where this import is coming from?

Comment: If you have a compiled version of the code, try opening the dll/exe in a tool like [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy) or [dnSpy](https://github.com/dnSpy/dnSpy) - use the search capabilities to find references to types from that namespace and see which assembly they resolve to.

Comment: An idea, not certain though.  If you can access their code, then write a line OpenDataAnswer.DataSchemas. <then look at the intellisense>, pick any class then method and 'peek' definition.  The peek window should show you the assembly details at the top.

Comment: Object Browser? Or right click on a class from its namespace and choose Go To Definition? The DLL name should be at the top

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual Studio you can put your cursor on the last identifier in the namespace (in the working version of your code) and hit F12. This will display all the assemblies that use the selected namespace:

[image]